# A scifi short story about a sound file that kills (or turns insane) the listener

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read it online maybe 5 to 10 years ago. It isn't *Carrier Wave* by Brockway.

People would weaponise the sound and try to infect people by essentially Rickrolling them (disguising the sound as another file). Some people deafened themselves and their children to protect them.

I recall that people committed suicide using the sound, but I might have misremembered.

Comment: It wasn’t spread through cell phone use, right? That might be *Cell* by Stephen King if so.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/BrownNote/Literature has a lot of examples that you might pick through.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No matches that I saw though. :D  I also checked some of the other relevant sub-pages like "Web Original."